# Listening to network traffic on Android

Tags: android, web-services, networking

Is there a way to monitor an app's internet data traffic? I am specifically interested in which webservice (URL) an app is calling, and what data is passed to it from my device. I have found some network monitor apps on google play that tells you the URL, but not the details of what data is passed, rendering it not useful.

thanks,
Joe

Comment: There was a wireshark port some time ago, good luck finding it. Requires root privileges, of course.

Comment: Maybe you could install the app into an emulator and run wireshark on the computer.